# How to remove a specific child from a sprite node?

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit, sprite, children

I'm working on a sprite kit game that displays 25 levels in world 1. What I'm trying to do is lock each level so I've added a locked.png image over top of the level icons. When the user reaches that level, I want to remove the locked icon so that the user can access the level.

The problem is that I've added BOTH the lock and level number as children, so when I go to `removeAllChildren` from `_level2`'s icon, it also removes the level number.

Is there a way to remove a single child from a spriteNode??

This is the code:

```
//Lock
SKSpriteNode *locked = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"Locked.png"];
locked.position = CGPointMake(0, 0);
locked.zPosition = 2.0;
locked.size = CGSizeMake(20*DoubleIfIpad, 20*DoubleIfIpad);
locked.color = [UIColor colorWithRed:255/255. green:156/255. blue:0/255. alpha:1.0];
locked.colorBlendFactor = 1.0;


_level2 = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithTexture:[SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:@"crate.png"] size:CGSizeMake(40*DoubleIfIpad, 40*DoubleIfIpad)];
_level2.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame)-50*DoubleIfIpad, CGRectGetMidY(self.frame)+50*DoubleIfIpad);
_level2.name = @"level2";

SKLabelNode *level2txt = [SKLabelNode labelNodeWithFontNamed:@"DIN Condensed"];
level2txt.position = CGPointMake(0, -8*DoubleIfIpad);
level2txt.fontColor = [SKColor whiteColor];
level2txt.fontSize = 20*DoubleIfIpad;
level2txt.text = @"2";
level2txt.name = @"level2";

[_level2 addChild:locked];

[_level2 addChild:level2txt];
[_levels addObject:_level2];
[self addChild:_level2];
```

What I've set up to unlock a level in a separate method:

```
if (highLevel >= 2) {
    [_level2 removeAllChildren];
}
```

Where `highLevel` is an NSInteger.

Comment: You tell a node to remove itself from its parent. Just like views.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Where `node` is the node you want to delete and `scene` is the parent node of `node`.

```
// when you create it
node.name = @"RemoveThisGuy"
[scene addChild:node];

// when you want to delete it
[[scene childNodeWithName:@"RemoveThisGuy"] removeFromParent];
```

Comment: @LiamStockhomme Anytime homeslice